# How to Paginate with Django Postman

Tags: django, web

I'm kinda new to Django, I'm working on a project that requires user to user messaging, so I decided to use Django postman. I was able to install in my project folder but the problem I'm facing has to do with pagination. The inbox should paginate after 20 messages but does not.

base_folder.html

```
<p>

    <div id="postman">
    <h1>{% block pm_folder_title %}{% endblock %}</h1>
    {% autopaginate pm_messages %}
    {% if invalid_page %}
    <p>{% trans "Sorry, this page number is invalid." %}</p>
    {% else %}
    {% if pm_messages %}
    {% b

lock pm_by_modes %}<div id="pm_byModes">

</p>
```

Really need help guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [FAQ in django-postman docs](http://django-postman.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html):

> I installed django-pagination, and still I don’t see any pagination widgets

```
Is there really more messages than one page capacity (default is 20)?
Check that pagination is declared before postman in the INSTALLED_APPS setting.
See if it’s better by disabling postman/templatetags/pagination_tags.py and .pyc (rename or move the files).
```

Comment: I have 23 messages in inbox so it should have used pagination already

Comment: If I'm not using an external pagination app like dj_pagination, do I still need to include "pagination" in settings?